# How to write out complex numbers using Fortran specifier

Tags: math, fortran, format, format-specifiers

I am new to Fortran and I have the following code, it basically solves a simple quadratic equation and output the solutions

```
!solving ax^2 + bx + c = 0

program output
  implicit none
  real :: a,b,c
  character :: response
  do 
    print*, 'Enter three coefficients a,b and c'
    read *, a,b,c 
    call quad(a,b,c)
    print*, 'Press Y to continue. Anykey for otherwise'
    read *, response
    if ( response /= 'y' .and. response /= 'Y') stop    
  end do
end program output

!Function to calculate Xs
subroutine quad(a,b,c)
  implicit none
  real :: a,b,c,xplus, xminus 

  xplus = ((-b)+sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)
  xminus = ((-b)-sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)

  if (xplus == xminus) then 
    print*, 'There exists 1 root only: '
    write(*,12) xplus
    12 format(2f10.2)
  else 
    print*, 'Solutions of quadratic equation are'
    write(*,10) xplus, xminus
    10 format(1f10.5)
  end if   

end subroutine quad
```

This works.  However, how would I go about with complex solutions.  I.e, how would this line change, to make the format for complex numbers.

```
10 format(1f10.5)
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: There are no complex numbers in your code. What do you want to output?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717223/writing-complex-matrix-in-fortran?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30291333/fortran-format-specifier-for-complex-number?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: Notably, this answers tells a lot https://stackoverflow.com/a/30291652/721644

Comment: Hello, this is what I meant.  Now, a,b,and c are coefficients of the quadratic.  If I type in a = 1, b = 2, c = 1 then the program works and prints out + and - roots.  However, if I have a = 4, b = 5, c = 3 then mathematically, we have complex roots, my program cannot print or write out complex.  It only prints the numbers as NaN

Comment: If you want to get complex value from `sqrt` you'll have to use a complex argument.

Comment: You need to use `complex` variables in your program to get complex results. Square root of real numbers is undefined for negative arguments.

Comment: See here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/2588280/721644

Comment: Thanks.  So I should do: 
complex :: xplus, xminus.  But what about the format specifier? For real number, I have something like 1f10.5.  What would it be for complex?

Comment: You need the _arguments_ of `sqrt` to be complex.  In this case, `a`, `b`, `c` (or some expression of those).  For output formatting, the questions linked earlier should answer.